# Django issue : UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, utf-8, ascii

I'm getting this common error in my code :

```
Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value:'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why ? Because I'm handling firstnames with french accents.

This is my code :

```
if 'rechercheGED' in request.GET:

        query_social_number = request.GET.get('q1social')

        sort_params = {}

        Individu_Recherche.set_if_not_none(sort_params, 'NumeroIdentification__iexact', query_social_number)

        query_lastname_list = Individu_Recherche.Recherche_Get(Individu, sort_params)

        lastname = query_lastname_list.Nom
        firstname = query_lastname_list.Prenom
        NIU = query_lastname_list.NumeroIdentification

        title = str(lastname + "_" + firstname + "_" + NIU)
```

The issue comes from : `firstname = query_lastname_list.Prenom`

Because in my case the firstname is `Jérôme`

I tried some things :

1) insert at the beginning :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

2) Use `firstname = query_lastname_list.Prenom.encode('utf-8')` and `firstname = query_lastname_list.Prenom.decode('utf-8')`

But up to now, impossible remove this error and handle data with accents.

Do you have any idea ?

**EDIT :**

This is the full Traceback :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/Identification/Person/Research/?q1social=19910-00001-634239-2&rechercheGED=Rechercher

Django Version: 1.10.3
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['Institution',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrapform',
 'django_countries',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'chartit',
 'Configurations',
 'Home',
 'Authentication',
 'Identity',
 'rest_framework']
Installed Middleware:
['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'DatasystemsCORE.middleware.OnlineNowMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/valentinjungbluth/Desktop/Django/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCore/DatasystemsCORE/Identity/views.py" in IdentityIndividuResearching
  454.         title = str(lastname + "_" + firstname + "_" + NIU)

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /Identification/Person/Research/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What python and django versions are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7 and Django 1.10.3 ;)

Comment: Is there some reason why you aren't using Python 3? It has much better Unicode handling, and Python 2 will reach its End of Life in 2020.

Comment: None, just because I began to study Python 3-4 years ago and it was Python 2.X
With Python 3 I will not have this kind of issue ?

Comment: First of all, show the full traceback; we can't even see where the error is happening. Secondly, show *how* you tried 'encode' and 'decode'. (And thirdly, stop randomly trying adding a coding declaration or `unicode_literals`; both only apply to literal characters *in your code*.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I edited my question thanks to your remarks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using Python 2.x, the problem does lie with the last line of the traceback.

```
title = unicode(str(lastname + "_" + firstname + "_" + NIU))
```

Either `lastname`, `firstname` or `NIU` contain characters that can not be represented by 7-bit ASCII, which is what `str` does (in Python 2).

Django comes with the useful functions `force_text` and `force_bytes` for these sorts of string casts, and also it's a good idea to use string interpolation instead of `+` when doing this sort of stuff:

```
from django.utils.text import force_text

title = force_text('%s_%s_%s' % (lastname, firstname, NIU))
```

Comment: Thank you it works very well ! Thanks to you I learned a new way to do this concatenation. I have just one question - If I have to use Python 3.x, Is it the same syntax than Python 2.x to do my process ?

Comment: Yes. The `%` syntax works in 3.x too, but be sure to check out https://pyformat.info/ to see everything you can do :)

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, your `title = str(lastname + "_" + firstname + "_" + NIU)` would work they way you expect. In Python 2, you're mixing Unicode and ASCII, so Python "helpfully" tries to convert the Unicode strings to ASCII so it can add them together, and of course that will fail if the Unicode cannot be represented in ASCII.

A simple way to fix this is to make everything Unicode. Eg,

```
firstname = u'Jérôme'
lastname = u'Pécresse'
title = lastname + u'_' + firstname
print title
```

**output**

```
Pécresse_Jérôme
```

---

I strongly recommend that you migrate to Python 3, it will make things much more pleasant, once you get used to the different (but far superior) handling of text and bytes.

In the mean time, you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! The only difference is that I'm picking data with accent from my database and make some processes later. So I can't write `u'Jérôme'` because this firstname comes from `MyModel.FirstnameField`

Comment: @Deadpool Understood. If `query_lastname_list.Nom` is an actual Unicode object (which it appears to be from your Traceback), then my code will still work. However, in Python 2 it's often simpler to encode everything to UTF-8, and work with that, as Ned explains in _Pragmatic Unicode_.